# ml kit object detection api template matching

Tags: object-detection, firebase-mlkit, template-matching

ML Kit allow you to detect & track objects in image/video frame, but is this possible that user choose a random object from the frame and ML Kit detect/track this object in image/subsequent video frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current API allows only "detected" objects to be tracked.